# Teamcity: trigger a build on a Tag with wildcard

Tags: git, teamcity

I'm a Teamcity newbe :) But I'm very well on the way.

I know that it is possible to trigger on Tags like this: +:refs/tags/(*)

Now my question is, is it possible to trigger on special Tags with wildcard? Like this: +:refs/tags/test_*. whenever a tag for example a tag "test_101" is pushed on Git that a build will start?

Furthermore, I read that with VCS rules it is possible to trigger on VCS comments. But I can't find anything about a "comment" What is mentioned with comment?

I hope I described my request understanble because I'm not a native speaker.

Thanks in advance and cheers

Answer (score 5):

Once you have "+:refs/tags/(*)" in the TeamCity Git VCS root, this makes the tags display as branches in TeamCity UI.

Then you can add +:test_* in the VCS trigger [branch filter](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Configuring+VCS+Triggers#ConfiguringVCSTriggers-BranchFilterbranchFilter) to make the tags trigger a new build.

VCS trigger also provides ability to trigger only on some commits matching commit comments. [Details](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Configuring+VCS+Triggers#ConfiguringVCSTriggers-VCSTriggerRules).

Comment: Hi Yaegor, Thanks for your Answer! I was able no to trigger with a Tag. But Only when I'm on another branch except the Master. When I add a Tag to the Master branch it is not triggered. Only when I'm on another branch it is triggered. I'd like to have it trigger by this way: devbranch -> Pull Request to Masterbranch after merging adding a Tag to the respective Masterbranch -> A now build will be triggered (When the special tag was recognized). Any Idea what I'm doing wrong? Many Thanks, much appreciate!

Comment: @kevdiablo, If you have Git tags in mind which appear under refs/tags, it should make no difference what branch the tags are created for. Only revision matters. I'd double-check the tags for which builds are now triggered and the others look the same from the Git perspective.

Comment: I can try what I want. When in the VCS root the default branch is "refs/heads/master" with Branch Specification "+:refs/tags/(*)" and in the trigger the Branch filter" with +:test_* a GIT tag in the master branch will not be recognized. But if I have in the VCS root in the default branch "refs/heads/dummy" and then I make a GIT tag on Master branch it is recognized and the trigger triggers a build. I tried it so many times.. maybe related to version 10.0.6 which are using ?Thanks in advance!

Comment: typo: "+:refs/tags/(*)" instead of "+:refs/tags/()"